# Software for Classical Music Theory / Composition / Harmony and Counterpoint

Tags: open-source, artificial-intelligence

Is there any software to help in learning / understanding / experimenting with the rules of harmony and counterpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a non-reading composer who has just "stuck with it" for so long that I've got a good handle on it now. I compose with the computer pretty much.

You could get a simple midi sequencer, or a really nice one like the one in Propellorhead Reason (great composing tool), experiment on your own, or download free midi files of Bach and other classical composers, then you can see where the notes are on the keyboard in the midi sequencer. Plus, you can move them around to see what happens.

A really good website for learning about voice leading and chord changes (progressions), is

http://www.musicnovatory.com/

It is not a very intuitive site to navigate. But, much can be learned their to help with making good sounding changes via voice leading and chord selection. Be patient and be very curious, that is, poke around a lot on the site, & you'll find gems.

Once you have some of that under your belt, get a decent book on counterpoint, and you'll be flyin' before you know it.

Answer (score 3):

Bach-style 4 part harmony actually does follow some pretty rigid rules (no parallel 4ths, 5th or octaves, for example), and once you get your head around the rules it is a fairly trivial matter to harmonise a melody in four parts.  That was the way I was taught at A-Level in the UK, and we weren't supposed to deviate from those rules - in fact, deviation was pretty much an instant mark-down.

However, as gnud said, the real good stuff comes from knowing which rules you can break where, and applying that knowledge intelligently.  I guess that one could write some software that could take a melody and come up with something that follows the rules, as well as some pre-defined ways of breaking or bending the rules.  I don't know of any, though.  Sorry. :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out Harmony Navigator from [Cognitone](http://cognitone.com/). I seems to be extactly what your are searching for...

Answer (score 1):

You could also check out ["CounterPointer" by Ars-Nova](http://www.ars-nova.com/cp/).

It is software that will drill you on voice leading and counterpoint according to Bach's vocal style rules.

Answer (score 0):

While very carefully coded applications could give you some hints, I find that the most important lesson is when to break the rules. And a computer program could never help with that.

I suggest you buy a book instead. Good ones include

- [The style of Palestrina and the dissonance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486442683)
- [Twentieth century harmony](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0393095398)

I haven't read any English books on baroque, wiener or romantic style.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to learn those things is kind of like the best way to program.  By actually playing music and listening to it.  I'm not sure how software would help with that.  A good selection of CDs, maybe some with lectures as well would be your best bet.

There is software out there to teach you how to play an instrument though.

Answer (score 0):

Find these books by Frederick Horwood entitled Theory, Harmony, and Counterpoint. No working, paid performance musician I have ever worked with has not found a benefit in the time-proven and transferable information contained in these three small books, which are directly applicable to the demands of live performance and the present state of music technology.

Comment: Are you talking about Elementary Counterpoint ? Because Theory, Harmony, and Counterpoint seems elusive if it ever existed.

Answer (score 0):

you could try the APP [MIND](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/midi-mind/id551958423?mt=8) or [MTBX MIDI Monitor](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/mtbx/id891039931?mt=12)

but the suggestion of study and listening is very true
Good luck with it all